# Pedestrian street crossing signs

Tags: gender, safety

Are there any geographies where pedestrian crossing signs indicate that it is ok for females to cross the street independently?

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a User Experience problem in need of a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Swedish Transport Agency allows two variants, one with pants and short hair and one with a skirt and long hair.

[image: Swedish road sign for pedestrian crossing][image: Swedish road sign for pedestrian crossing, alternate design]

Both variants are used and there is no distinction in meaning. While none of them is identical to the designs I could see in the Vienna convention documents (none of them is wearing a hat), I would say they are both unmistakable.

Answer (score 3):

## No

Countries that have signed the **Vienna Convention on Road Signs and Signals** use the same, or similar, set of pictograms to ensure easy recognition. You can refer to the [**manuals here**](https://unece.org/road-traffic-and-road-signs-and-signals-agreements-and-conventions).

Even those that haven't signed the treaty, such as the [**Southern African Development Community**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_African_Development_Community), adopt the same conventions with minor variations. The [**manuals for SADC-RTSM can be found here**](https://www.sartsma.co.za/sadc-manual-v4).

Furthermore, some nations that did not join the treaty adhere to the US-based [**MUTCD system**](https://mutcd.fhwa.dot.gov/). Introduced in 1935, the MUTCD system has influenced many Vienna Convention signs, ensuring a level of uniformity worldwide.

However, regardless of the similarities or differences between these systems, **none incorporate gender variations**.

This is logical: a figure representing a *"man"* is only discerned as such if there's a corresponding *"woman"* figure. Without this distinction, the figure could represent any gender. Introducing additional cues, like a *"dress"* to indicate a *"woman"*, would only impose unnecessary cognitive load, complicating matters rather than clarifying.

It's worth noting that I use quotes to emphasize that **these symbols aren't literal but are understood through societal symbolism.** In the real world, what we perceive as a dress might not be just that. Men might wear dresses, women might choose not to, and someone depicted in a "dress" might not identify with any specific gender. Such complexities of representation are highlighted in semiotics through concepts like the Triangle of Reference or Ogden's Semiotic Triangle.